# How can the javax validator return a not null, but still empty, list of constraints?

Tags: hibernate-validator

I can see the javax validator returning a non null list of constraints. But that list contains 0 elements.

How can that be ?

It flies in the face of my test coverage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean any of the various `validate()`, `validateValue()` etc. methods on `Validator`, returning an empty set of `ConstraintViolation` is the indicator that the requested validation was successful, i.e. no constraints were violated.

Returning an empty collection instead of null is a common best practice to avoid `NullPointerException`s on the caller's side. Check `isEmpty()` on the returned set to find out whether the validation was successful or not.

Comment: All right, I was also checking for the list of constraints not to be null before checking for it not to be empty. I guess I can ditch the not to be null check and only keep the not to be empty one.